# how to check database on develop profile?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am working on `jhipster Release 0.7.0` and i am running project on develop profile.

i want to check in-memory Database for testing.

please give me some solution that hot to check in memory database on develop profile.

please give me some solution ASAP

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access HSQLDB from outside the JHipster process ? I'm afraid it's not possible, at least not easily.

If you want to do that kind of thing, I would recommend you switch to another database for development, for instance MySQL.

With JPA and Liquibase this shouldn't be difficult to switch, and then you would have all the tools offered by MySQL to audit and manage your database.